# How can I merge objects while maintaining the materials in Sverchok?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, sverchok

Is it possible to merge objects in Sverchok while transferring the materials to the new objects?

Here is  a screenshot that shows the issue. I merged the objects with the material indexes but no materials are on the new object.

[image]

I am also attaching the test blend file

[blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/c3f50690017e4cf787d634e9754d7677)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have not such node yet, and object in function. because was no needs.
Simple per polygon approach is here:
https://gist.github.com/81d278ada5a769c91d0a1fe9351dc53f

But in your particular case we can add index to shift materials, not universal solution:
https://gist.github.com/21a427f325312daa5086e635505430cf
[image]